# NetworkOnMainThread Exception Thrown even with AsyncTask

Tags: android

Here is the AsyncTask class within my Fragment and when I click on the fragment,  I get this error:
NetworkOnMainThread Exception (I can't post an image because my reputation isn't high enough)

```
private class me extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Boolean>{   
           DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

           protected void onPreExecute(){
               String sess = SignIn.giveSession().getSession().getToken();


               deviceId = device.getDeviceId();
               data = RestQuery.profileImage(sessionToken, deviceId, username);
               bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
               getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);


               username = reWiPr.getName();



           }

           protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... stuff){
               if(reWiPr == null){
                   return false;
               }

               return true;
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(Boolean results){
               if(results){
                   image.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
                   image.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
                   image.setImageBitmap(bm);

                   uName.setText(reWiPr.getName());
                   rName.setText(reWiPr.getRealName());
                   safety.setText("Safety: " + reWiPr.getRating().getSafe());
                   time.setText("Time: " + reWiPr.getRating().getTime());
                   courteous.setText("Courteous: " + reWiPr.getRating().getCourteous());
                   cleanliness.setText("Cleanliness: " + reWiPr.getRating().getClean());
                   overall.setText("Overall: " + reWiPr.getRating().getOverall());
                   average.setText("Average: " + reWiPr.getRating().getAverage());
                   ve.setText("Vehicles: " + reWiPr.getVehicle() );


               }
           }
```

How do I fix this? I need this AsyncTask to make the fragment work and I execute it in the onCreate() method. Any help would be appreciated thanks.*

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing the network call in the correct method. You have to move your network call in `doInBackground` which I see is in `onPreExecute` right now.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is
>    executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>    by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread
>    immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is
>    used to perform background computation that can take a long time.
>    The parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>    result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>    passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>    publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of
>    progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>    onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call
>    to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>    undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in
>    the user interface while the background computation is still
>    executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or
>    show logs in a text field.
> 4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>    computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>    passed to this step as a parameter.

Comment: My network call is the one with RestQuery and I moved that to the doInBackground, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It turns out that i'm using a method from another class which uses the data call outside the doInBackground. Is there anyway to create a method inside the doInBackground of an AsyncTask and then call that method in another separate class(not the parent class)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your network tasks in the `doInBackground` method. At the moment you have in `onPreExecute` which runs on the GUI thread.